# Typescript megring namespaces in d.ts files

Tags: angular, typescript, namespaces, electron, typescript-typings

Now I`m trying merge namespaces from d.ts
Example:

When I tried megre namespaces in one file, all is well.

```
declare namespace tst {
    export interface info {
        info1: number;
    }
    var a: info;
}

declare namespace tst {
    export interface info {
        info2: number;
    }
}

tst.a.info1 = 1;
tst.a.info2 = 1;
```

But when I moved first namespace to test.d.ts - all is brokes

**test.d.ts**

```
declare namespace tst {
    export interface info {
        info1: number;
    }
    var a: info;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />

declare namespace tst {
    export interface info {
        info2: number;
    }
}

// Module to control application life.
tst.a.info1 = 1;
tst.a.info2 = 1; // Error:(31, 7) TS2339: Property 'info2' does not exist on type 'info'.
```

I met this problem when I added new method to Electron, Angular2 and etc types.
Example:

in **electron/index.d.ts**

```
declare namespace Electron {
    interface App extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
        ...
    }
}
```

in my file **test.ts**

```
declare namespace Electron {
    interface App extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
        isQuiting?: boolean;
    }
}
```

I got this error: TS2339: Property 'isQuiting' does not exist on type 'App'.

Do I can merge custom namespaces with **d.ts**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1) Remove all import/export from *.ts ([You can read about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39793404/2051938))

2) Create new file *.d.ts (example test.extend.d.ts),
write all cnanges into *.d.ts file,
import this file: `/// <reference path="*.d.ts" />`

**Example:**

File: **test.d.ts**

```
declare namespace Electron {
    interface App extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
        isQuiting?: boolean;
    }
}
```

File: **test.ts**

```
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />
import {...} from "..."; // Any import/export
app.isQuiting = false; // IT WORKS!!!
app.quit(); // types of electron work too!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is root import\export in files:

> If you have an import or an export at the root level of a TypeScript
>   file then it creates a local scope within that file.

[Read more here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html)

So the first file **tst**, and the second file **tst** in different scopes and can't be merged. You must remove all root import\export from file, or move it to separated file.

Comment: for example file **test.ts**
`import { importClass } from "./someFile.ts"

declare namespace Electron {
    interface App extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
        isQuiting?: boolean;
    }
}

export class SomeClass {
}`

must not contain export\import directives

Comment: but I can't works without import/export! I imports electron and etc libs to my file and works with him. This variant as "no file - no problem"

Comment: I think u can do for merged namespace something like:
**electron.d.ts** - not contain import\export, and contain default electron structure
**electron.extended.d.ts** - not contain import\export and contain you extensions
**tst.ts** - containt nessesary import\export and have access to both electron files, since they in global scope.

Comment: Also I use a "module" instead "namespace", may be it do some influence. And if your *.d.ts have imoprt\export, i think it is bad, and you must remove it. For example correct electron.d.ts - [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts). By the way you can add your extension in  one electron.d.ts file, but it can have bad influence in future, then u may want to change it.